# How to avoid the library mismatch problem in linux

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I need to find out the correct way to avoid the below reccurence of the problem.

We have a `cpp` library which will read the data from `httpd` and send that data to one of our application. So the problem is the library is built with `apr` library. The problem is for many customers they are or might be running with newer Appache along with some other version of the `apr` library. Which is causing our library to fail with unresolved external symbols. To fix this what we are doing is building our library with same exact version of the `apr` library that the customer has and then we ship. So this a reoccurring problem as the customer are updating their Appache to the latest then again we see the same issue and will repeat the steps.

Is there any way to handle this kind of problem from occurring again in future?

Comment: A common way is to bundle the sources of the apr library with your product and link it statically.

Comment: Welcome to Linux. It is the only major operating system that regularly suffers path problems in 2018 (soon to be 2019). AIX, BSDs, OS X, Solaris and even Windows solved it decades ago. In the meantime, build your application with `-Wl,-R,<origin path> -Wl,--enable-new-dtags`. Ship your version of the libraries with the application. It should cause you to fail early rather than late.